# Personalization rule by GeoIP -> Business name

Tags: personalization, geo-location

Does anyone know how the following rule works:

*where the **business name** compares to specific value*

[image: personalization rule by business name]

What is it the **Business name** and how it populates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Where the Business Name Compares to Specific Value Rule**

In some cases, a business or institution may be available for an IP address. This rule compares against that name. The incidences of these are rather low, however, and when they are not available, the name of the user's ISP is exposed to be tested against.

Please look here http://www.berndtgroup.net/thinking/blog/sitecore/explaining-sitecore-dms-geographic-personalization-rules, few rules are explained.

**Business Name**: the name of the organization, institution, or business that belongs to the IP address. Often this value and the ISP correspond, leading to misidentification. As a result, this value is only effective for targeting large businesses or corporations whose have large and identifiable networks. Not good for targeting wider geographic areas or small, local businesses.

http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2017/01/Exploring-the-capabilities-of-geographic-personalization-in-Sitecore.aspx

Comment: Only two things I'd add, is that the Sitecore Geo IP service can populate that field, but the data quality (as mentioned) is not necessarily that good. There are however other data providers that can provide better quality data, but that does come at a cost.